# Cannot match integer value using regex - error (at <stdin>:6): number not a string or array

Tags: json, regex, jq

I have multiple JSON files with  a person's age and I want to match specific ages using regex, however, I cannot be able to match even a single integer in a file.

I can select age using following `jq`,

```
jq -r .details.Age
```

I can match `Name` using following `jq`,

```
jq -r 'select(.details.Name | match("r.*"))'
```

But when I try to use `test` or `match` with `Age` I get following error,

```
jq -r 'select(.details.Age | match(32))'
jq: error (at <stdin>:6): number not a string or array
```

Here is code,

```
{
  "details": {
    "Age": 32,
    "Name": "reverent"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to match `Age` using `jq` something like this,

```
jq -r 'select(.details.Age | match(\d))'
```

Comment: Because i want to replace literal 32 to match any number using regex.

Comment: Thank you tried that. please let me be more specific. I want to match by providing specific numbers to match for value of Age. Like either 32 and 34. I played around with Age range 1-9 using [1-9] and I could see that i can only use match or test to match regex but it doesn't work with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .Age value is a number, but regexes work on strings, so if you really want to use regexes, you would have to transform the number to a string. This can be done using `tostring`, but please remember that the `tostring` representation of a JSON number might not always be what you think it will be.

–––

p.s. That should be `match("\\d")`

Comment: why can I not match numbers using regex?

Comment: It’s a fact of life. If you find a software tool that seems to enable one to use regexes with numbers, you’ll find it works on a string representation of the number (and probably a decimal one at that).